# Google map and divs interaction similar to Groupon.com/now

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Can someone help me understand how to get the tight interaction between the map, list views and div marker elements on the "Groupon Now" UI.

You can check it out here: [www.groupon.com/now](http://groupon.com/now)

How can I get the list items to highlight when I hover over/click an item on the map?

I've tried to do it with built in google map markers, but I would like to know how groupon uses additional divs to achieve this.

Comment: provide code snippets of what you have tried, and what exactly you are trying to achieve.